# Comunicacion entre dos clases

Tags: android

Tengo una clase A que contiene un ArrayList, Tambien tengo una clase B en la que quiero poder añadir un item al ArrayList ¿Como puedo añadir el item al array perteneciente a la otra clase?

Clase A:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<Item> lista = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        makeList();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.settings:

                Intent inten = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(inten);
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }
```

Clase B:

```
public class AddItem extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_item);
}

    public void addItem(){

        EditText tex1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nombre);
        String nombre = "" + tex1.getText();

        Item item1 = new Item(nombre);
        //AQUI DEBERIA IR UN 
        //lista.add(item1) 
        //PERO LA VARIABLE lista PERTENECE A LA CLASE A

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas utilizar [`setActivityForResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) que le indica a la nueva activida que estas esperando un valor de ella.

Esto seria en tu clase a:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.settings:

                Intent inten = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(inten, 150);
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }
```

En tu clase b cuando termines y sepas que elemento es que quieres agregar al ArrayList, le asignas el [`setResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int)) para indicarle al activity que debe de enviarle el valor al activity anterior:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("elementoParaElArrayList", "valor")
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);        
finish();
```

Entonces para recibir ese valor sobre escribes `onActivityResult` en tu clase a:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 150) {
         if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             String valorLista = data.getStringExtra("elementoParaElArrayList");
             // agregas el elemento a la lista.
         }     
    }
}
```

**Actualizacion:**

Ahora me detengo a leer bien tu pregunta(mala mia).

Tu intención es tener la referencia del `ArrayList` de la clase `MainActivity` en la clase `AddItem`. Esto no se puede a menos que hagas la lista `static` y no es recomendable por la complejidad que requiere saber si limpiar la lista o no, si agregar elementos a la lista o no, si eliminar un elemento de la lista o no...

Pero al final cada cual al final decide el diseño de su aplicación.

**Enviar objeto propio**

Si lo que quieres es enviar un objeto propio. Sencillamente implementa la interfaz [`Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).

```
public class Item implements Serializable{
 // ...
}
```

Y obtienes el objeto serializable del result utilizando [`getSerializableExtra(string key)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getSerializableExtra(java.lang.String)) del intent:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 150) {
         if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             Item valorLista = (Item)data.getSerializableExtra("elementoParaElArrayList");
             // agregas el elemento a la lista.
         }     
    }
}
```

Comment: Segun tu solucion lo que pasaria seria un String ¿no? En intent.putExtra() no me deja pasarle mi "item" y el metodo data.getExtra no lo encuentra AndroidStudio

Comment: Si. Todos los datos primitivos son soportados. Si quieres enviar y recibir un objeto propio debes de implementar la interfaz [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html)

Comment: ¿Podrias adaptarlo a mi codigo? Soy un poco nuevo en esto y no entiendo muy bien lo de Serializable

Comment: @Jose, mra la respuesta actualizada.

Comment: Si te sirvio, no olvides marcarla como la aceptada.